# Passing html context to jquery's 2nd param give me null values, why?

Tags: jquery

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong here:

```
var typeSelect = "<input class='typeSelect' type='text' value='test' />";
alert($('input', typeSelect).attr('value'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a second argument as a context to [`$()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/), it's doing this:

```
$(typeSelect).find('input').attr('value')
```

...and since that `<input>` isn't a *child*, it finds no elements.  If the `<input>` *was* a child, [it would work](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/QKY93/).

In your case since it's not, you just need this:

```
$(typeSelect).attr('value')
```

[You can test it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/QKY93/1/).

Comment: Yes, that works. Now why cant I manipulate that data I wonder?
var typeSelect = "<input type='text' value='test' />";
$(typeSelect).attr('value', 'red');alert($(typeSelect).val());

Comment: @Derrick - Because when you do that, you're creating a new object from the original HTML each time..you need to create it once then change it, like this: http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/QKY93/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
alert($(typeSelect).val());
```

I think!?

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter in JQuery is used for the document scope so it used  to pass a document type object and its used for other cases , like if you want to run your JQuery function on another window document or inside an iFrame.
in your case you can use this technique :

```
var typeSelect = document.createElement("div");
$(typeSelect).html("<input class='typeSelect' type='text' value='test' />");

alert($(typeSelect).find("input").attr('value'));
```

this will create a document object variable with a "div" type and save your html context inside it , and then feel free to do anything on it ;)